# How can I truncate a text and use the second part of the text?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm researching for a little problem.
I get on my Django template a text. The point is truncate that text, and add the second part of the text in other tag.
I read about:

```
{{ value|truncatechars_html:x }}
```

It can works, but I can't use the second part of truncated text.

If someone has an idea...Thanks!!!!

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in django filter for that. Define your own custom template tag and use that filter. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slice - [see docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice). Strings in python are also lists of characters, so you can do something like this:

```
First part is {{ value|slice:":x" }}
Second part is {{ value|slice:"x+1:" }}
```

HOWEVER, if you need to keep some html code, slice won't do it. For that, you will need to write your own custom tag (you can look into the code from truncate chars) which returns two values - one for each part of your string.

Assuming your filter returns something like this:

```
def your_truncate_filter(value, arg):
    ... # your code for splitting
    data = {}
    data['first'] = "....." # first part of string with html tags !!!
    data['second'] = "....." # second part of string
    return data
```

you can access it in your template like this:

```
{% with parts=value|your_truncate_filter:x %}
     {{ parts.first }}
     {{ parts.second }}

{% endwith %}
```